# Filter over jsonfiled with unknown keys in Django ORM

Tags: json, django, orm

There is a model with JSONfield in Django model:

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
    is_info = models.BooleanField()
    info = models.JSONField()
```

The data inside table is like:

| is_info | info |
| --- | --- |
| false |  |
| true | {'key123':{'a':'1', 'b':'2', 'search_key':'text'},'key456':{'a':'1', 'b':'2', 'search_key':'another_value'}} |

And I need to filter somehow a query set to receive a set of rows where compound key `'search_key'='text'` and not include in result values from 'info' field where 'search_key' has some other values.
My keys of 'info' field (key123, key456 and etc.) are always different and I don't know the exact value.

Please, help me!!!)

I've tried:

```
q = queryset.filter(info__icontains='text')
```

but it return for me all the field info:

```
{'key123':{'a':'1', 'b':'2', 'search_key':'text'},'key456':{'a':'1', 'b':'2', 'search_key':'another_value'}}
```

when I need to receive only:

```
{'key123':{'a':'1', 'b':'2', 'search_key':'text'}}
```

Comment: queryset.filter(info__contains={'search_key': 'text'})

Comment: It returns an error: NotSupportedError: contains lookup is not supported on this database backend ((

Comment: Okay so you dont use Postgres as a database. What database are you using? (In terms of the JSONField, I can really suggest you to move to postgres as a database backend)

Comment: I'm using MySQL)) I will try with Posgres - thank you!)

Comment: No problem. Here are some useful links for the jsonfield: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#jsonfield https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#querying-jsonfield